# How can I get Steam to work on my MacBook Air via PlayOnMac?

Tags: steam, macos

I can't run Steam on PlayOnMac on my 2020 MacBook Air M1 8GB RAM. I want to be able to use my MacBook for playing Half-Life when I don't have access to my gaming PC. When I run Steam, it just gives me a blank Steam window, no option to login. I did not try to install other things, and I have confirmed Steam has installed correctly.

[image: Screenshot of blank window with only a close button in the upper-right.]

Comment: why do you need PlayOnMac? why can't you use regular macOS steam version? is it because 64-bit only limitation?